# I don't know how to generate a postgresql report

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I am trying to create a select with 3 columns, in the first one some name, in the second column a year and in the third I need to have a list of words that appear in a different table . Basically I need something like this:

```
 Name     Year      List
 A        1990      R1,R2,R3
 B        1992      R4,R5,R6,R7
```

The R1-R7 appear in a table, but one in each row. How may I join them to have a report with more than one word in a row?

This is the table with the R1-R7:

```
  X     Y    CC    YEAR
  1     2    R1    1990
  2     3    R2    1990
  3     4    R3    1990
  4     5    R4    1992
  .............
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where do the values for `x` and `y` come from?

Comment: Kinda irrelevant, it's just another 2 columns from the table where I extract the CC column. I only need the CC column

Comment: I know how to join the tables, my only problem is how to make more words appear on the same row on only one column

Comment: So what is the relationship between the tables?

Comment: looks like you need `string_agg`, though can't tell more, because your provide  info is little bit  unclear.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the second table a bit. Maybe now it's a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
select year, string_agg(cc, ',')
from t
group by year
```